# Positioning an EditText within in ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm working on an app where I've got an ImageView on my main screen, and would like to be able to position an EditText at a fixed location within the image regardless of the screen size.

I've been able to accomplish this for some of the supported screen sizes using FrameLayout with android:layout_marginTop for the EditText, however for many of the sizes it doesn't quite work out.

Any tips for accomplishing this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand you want to make your design look equal on every android device.

Try `setting the marging programatically` by `getting the screen size`.

Comment: I ended up programmatically setting the Y coordinate of the EditText using a known ratio describing where the EditText was supposed to be in the image multiplied by the height of the ImageView at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a non-Image view, or perhaps even an android layout to encapsulate images.
You can alter the background image of all views to behave like an image view.

Within your layout you can place a text view that would move relative to an image being refactored on several devices.

Comment: so i've got a RelativeLayout with the background pointing to my drawable, which contains my EditText. At the risk of sounding like a pedant, how do I set the EditText position relative to the background drawable? I'm not seeing anything in the docs that would allow for such a relationship... thanks!

Comment: You can either edit the xml. Or, quite literally, drag and drop it to the top left corner and adjust margins using density independent pixel values(dp). These density independent pixels maintain a consistent size across devices with varying resolution. Unfortunately, There is no native-fix to make things scale like they do in CSS. If you're looking for more control over scaling. You can always edit values in start() or onCreate() methods of your activity. There is no reason to do it this way when a simple relative anchor on corners would do the same thing.